# Grouping by with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, grouping

How can I use `LINQ` to achieve the following?

I have some c# object (I write them as `JSON` for simplification only)

```
{ Name: A, Domain: a, SubDomain: 1}
{ Name: B, Domain: a, SubDomain: 2}
{ Name: C, Domain: b, SubDomain: 1}
{ Name: D, Domain: b, SubDomain: 2}
{ Name: E, Domain: c, SubDomain: 1}
```

I want to gather them as:

```
{ Domain: a ,{{Name: A, SubDomain: 1}, {Name: B, SubDomain: 2}}
  Domain: b ,{{Name: C, SubDomain: 1}, {Name: D, SubDomain: 2}}
  Domain: c ,{{Name: E, SubDomain: 1}}
```

Comment: `GroupBy(x => x.Domain)`

Comment: Are you tried to google? [code.msdn](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just want to group by `Domain` ?

```
var list = GetListFromFoo();
var groupedList = list.GroupBy(x => x.Domain);
```

It was done with this `LINQ` method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> GroupBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx)

---

If I understood your comment right, this is what you are looking for:

```
var groupedList = list.GroupBy(x => x.Domain, x => new
                                        {
                                            x.Name,
                                            x.SubDomain
                                        });
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx)

Comment: Two things: a) the elements under each key are still of the original type, not omitting the mutual key. b)the key isn't a member of the collection it's not reflected after JSON serializtion

Comment: @EladBenda. Please show the class members, and what do you want the final type to be.

Comment: `{ Domain: a ,{{Name: A, SubDomain: 1}, {Name: B, SubDomain: 2}}
  Domain: b ,{{Name: C, SubDomain: 1}, {Name: D, SubDomain: 2}}
  Domain: c ,{{Name: E, SubDomain: 1}}`